# Cor 1.2.28 (Finite pullback) in Lazarsfeld's Book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry

I meet some problem when reading Lazarsfeld's *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry*, Cor 1.2.28.

> **Corollary 1.2.28** Let $f:Y\longrightarrow X$ be a finite surjective mapping of projective schemes, and let $L$ a line bundle on $X$, if $f^*L$ is ample on $Y$, then $L$ is ample on $X$.

The proof states as below.

> *Proof.* Let $V\subseteq X$ be an irreducible variety. Since $f$ is surjective and finite, there exists irreducible variety $W\subseteq Y$ mapping finite onto $V$: we start with $f^{-1}(V)$, one constructs $W$ by taking irreducible components and $\color{blue}{\textrm{cutting down by general hyperplanes}}.$ Then by the projection formula:

$$\int_W {c_1(f^*L)}^{\text{dim}W}=\text{deg}(W\longrightarrow V)\cdot\,\int_V{c_1(L)}^{\text{dim}(V)}$$

> By applying the Nakai-Moishezon ampleness criterion, we are done.

What confuses me is the $\color{blue}{\textrm{'blue'}}$ sentence, **why we need the general hyperplane cut-down procedure?**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I concur that $f^{-1}(V)\to V$ is finite surjective (both properties are preserved under arbitrary base change) - perhaps the blue sentence is used in the application of Nakai-Moishezon?

Comment: To piggyback off of @KReiser: in the situation where the line bundle is very ample, its first Chern class is literally the class of a general hyperplane section in the associated projective embedding, so raising it to a power $k$ amounts to intersecting $k$ general hyperplanes to get a codimension $k$ linear space, and then intersecting it with the embedded variety. While doing this with an ample-but-not-very-ample bundle doesn't have an equally clean geometric description, it's perfectly reasonable (and all that is needed) on the level of cohomology/Chow/whatever.

Comment: I suppose the "point" of doing this is because this is what Nakai-Moishezon requires. Ampleness implies by N-M that a certain class of intersection numbers on $Y$ are all positive, which by the projection formula implies positivity of the necessary intersection numbers to apply N-M on $X$. I will say that if you quoted this directly like your post suggests, it's a rather strange way of phrasing things on Lazarsfeld's part.

Comment: Dear @Tabes Bridges, thanks a lot! Happy New Year.

Comment: Dear @KReiser, thanks for your comment. Happy new year!